# Flat List not maintaining unique List?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I wanted to know if KeyExtrator contributes to maintain the unique list ?
if yes then its not helping me at all.

I am trying to display elements on flat list when a new Item comes in, the list just addes it without checking for uniqueness of the list

Main goal is to make my list unique, I had tried ListView It was working 
 due to logic implemented using rowHasChanged method.trying to see if there is anything for FlatList.

```js
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      TESTDATA: [{
        BarCode: '1',
        StopAddress: 'Label 1'
      }]
    };
  };

  onReceivedMessage(messages) {
    var jsondata = JSON.parse(messages)
    var dataTest = this.state.TESTDATA;
    var Data = addressToDataMap.get(dataTest.BarCodes);
    dataTest.push(jsondata);

    this.setState({
      TESTDATA: dataTest
    });
  }
```

```
<FlatList
      extraData={this.state}
        data={this.state.TESTDATA}
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.BarCode.toString()}
        renderItem={({ item}) => (
      <Text style={styles.baseText}>
        Stop Address: {item.StopAddress}{'\n'}
        Barcodes:    {item.BarCode}
            </Text>
        )}
/>
```

Comment: Whether the below explanation was useful?

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to know if KeyExtrator contributes to maintain the unique list ? **NO is the Answer**

**Explanation :** keyExtractor tells the list to use the ids for the react keys instead of the default key property. Keys help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are removed. Key also used for caching and as the react key to tracking item re-ordering. These unique keys are what allow the VirtualizedList (which is what FlatList is built on) to track items and are really important in terms of efficiency. The keyExtractor falls back to using the index by default. For example

```
<FlatList
  style={{}}
  data={this.state.FeedDataCollection}
  keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.key}
  renderItem={(rowData) =>this.RenderFeedCard(rowData)}
/>
```

Here `item.key` is is key.So if you want display elements based on the uniqueness, you have write a logic for that. keyExtractor cant do that. Learn more about React Keys here https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html and KeyExtractor here https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#keyextractor